# How to determine the Content-Type in an HTTP Response

Tags: apache, http, web, webserver

I'm building a web server as an exercise. When I receive a raw request, it gets parsed into an simple syntax tree, and a response is built by evaluating this tree. My question this: **`When sending an HTTP Response, does the Content-Type field get set by taking the file extension of the requested resource and looking it up in a dictionary of MIME-types?`** A good example would be the anatomy of how the response for a favicon.ico is built. Any insight into this would be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a college homework question...

Comment: I'll just assume the answer is what I thought... That you take the file extension of the requested resource, and look it up in your MIME mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, web server looks into file extension and select what kind of Content Type it should interpret the file as. However, server-side scripting can send custom header ( e.g. `header()` function of PHP ) to override the settings . For example, a JPEG can be interpreted as PNG if you send Content Type as `image/png` to web server with the following code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

For non-file requests, the web server looks into custom header directly.

Web server maps extension with MIME type. As you tag [apache](/questions/tagged/apache), Apache uses [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) to identify file's MIME type, while IIS and other web servers have similar settings .

Comment: This does not answer my question. I'm asking HOW the Content-Type field is derived. Not how MIME mappings work.

Comment: Content-Type is MIME Type.

Comment: Still does not answer the question. Let me rephrase: *HOW* does the server know what type to lookup in the MIME mapping?